# How do you create an isolated, positive voltage?

Tags: isolation

I know this seems like a simplistic question, but I am a beginner here....

Multiple web sites pop up on Google talking about how to create a negative voltage, but what about positive?

The Wikipedia page, for instance on 'field-ion microscope' talks about the necessity of creating (and maintaining) a positive voltage in the tip....

Comment: If it is an isolated voltage there is no defined voltage to ground and the resistance to ground is very high. An isolated voltage needs a pair of terminals, one of them is positive in respect to the other one. You may connect the positive or the negative terminal of the isolated voltage to ground or to a ground related voltage. There is no single isolated positive voltage without the respective negative terminal. The same is true for a single isolated negative voltage without the respective positive terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wish to create DC voltage, A flyback DC to DC converter (Switching circuit+ transformer + rectifier) will create an isolated voltage differential, which you can wire either way to your load.

Answer (score 2):

The default for a power supply in recent years is positive with respect to ground, so sometimes when a supply negative wrt ground is required we make it from the positive supply.

A field ion microscope requires a high voltage supply of 5-10kV according to [that page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_ion_microscope). Generally you'd want to make that from a lower voltage DC supply in 2020. Years ago we might just buy a mains power transformer that had a HV secondary and use a doubler or tripler to get the high voltage, but that would be relatively heavy and expensive.

It's not necessarily any more difficult to make a negative voltage wrt ground than a positive, but the supply may have to be designed for that because of insulation requirements.

If you wanted to experiment with something like that, the easiest approach is to buy a HV DC-DC converter such as [this](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_E_Series.pdf) one. That particular product has sufficient isolation it can be used for negative or positive supplies. Proper care MUST be taken so it so it **should only be attempted by someone familiar with safely dealing with high voltages**.

[image]